# how to change datatype of a column in data table through code?

Tags: c#

I want to change datatype of column name called "FaxNo" from int to numeric..
I tried with this code..

```
 private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
        string s = "ALTER TABLE Add_Information ALTER COLUMN FaxNo numeric(18,0)";

            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s, con);
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() >= 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Successfully updaed");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Not done");
            }
            con.Close();     
    }
```

My table name is `Add_Information`
It is showing message as `Not done`.
Help me out to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess You cannot change the DataType of a DataColumn after populating it with data. It's not a read-only property, but you will receive an exception at runtime if you attempt to change it after it already has data.

According to msdn document linked below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.datatype.aspx:

**An exception is generated when changing this property after the column has begun storing data.**

So you will have to either ensure the correct column types in the beginning (if possible), or create a new DataTable specifically for the import and copy data from the original DataTable.